# LINQ query with variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi guys I am trying to do a query in LINQ in C# in .NET MVC with the following code:

```
public int Delete(int id)
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
            {
                var student = db.Students.Find(id);
                var curso = from t in db.Teachers
                            join i in db.Inscriptions on id equals i.StudentId
                            where t.Id == i.StudentId
                            select i.Id;
                var atten = from a in db.Attendances
                            where a.InscriptionId == curso
            }
        }
```

I am trying to compare the query that I am doing to a variable that already contains a value.
I am trying to compare this : `where a.InscriptionId == curso`
Curso being the variable that contains the value that I need to compare.

How can I do This ?

Comment: The value type of curso probably needs to be casted to an integer (or whatever data type you're trying to compare to). `where a.InscriptionId == (int)curso`

Comment: You `curso` return `IEnumerable<>` from the query, regardless of the fact that you know it's only going to have 0 or 1 elements. So you need to do something like `var cursoId = curso.FirstOrDefault()` then use cursoId instead

Comment: @NSGaga You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @NetMage I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use another join and return both as an object? something like...

```
var student = db.Students.Find(id);
var CursoAndAtten = (from t in db.Teachers
                        join i in db.Inscriptions on i.id equals i.StudentId
                        join a in db.Attendances on a.InscriptionId equals 
                        i.Id
                        where t.Id == i.StudentId
                        select new { curso = i.Id, atten = a}).ToList()// Or e.g FirstOrDefault() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return a type `IEnumerable<int>` instead of int.

Try selecting the single element at the end of the query by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
public int Delete(int id)
    {
        using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
        {
            var student = db.Students.Find(id);
            var curso = from t in db.Teachers
                        join i in db.Inscriptions on id equals i.StudentId
                        where t.Id == i.StudentId
                        select i.Id;
            var atten = from a in db.Attendances
                        where a.InscriptionId == curso.FirstOrDefault() //this line was modified
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Try casting as an integer` ? I mean did you just compile all the comments together? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `curso` is `IEnumerable<>` (as that's what's returned from the query), regardless of the fact that you **know** it's only going to have 0 or 1 elements.

You can do something like

```
var cursoId = curso.FirstOrDefault()
```

then use `cursoId` instead.

**note**: you should probably test and handle the `default`, when no elements are returned, avoid going into the next query, do something else I guess.

And an advise, just hover your cursor over the var variable to see its actual type.